# ubuntu wireless on hp stream 11

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom, hp

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on hp stream 11. Wireless device is not being detected.

Windows detects it as Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 bgn.

Is it possible to get the drivers for Ubuntu and install manually?

EDIT: I downloaded packages manually, now getting another error

````
$ sudo dpkg -i dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 164809 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5) over (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
compX@compX-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 164809 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) over (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.19.0-25-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.19.0-25-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
compX@compX-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ more /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log 
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom for kernel 3.19.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Thu Jan 14 21:21:06 GMT 2016
make: Entering directory ```/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function â€˜wl_alloc_linux_ifâ€™:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:64: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
  dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(priv_link_t), intf_name, ether_setup);
                                                                ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:8: error: â€˜alloc_netdevâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
  dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(priv_link_t), intf_name, ether_setup);
        ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each funct
ion it appears in
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
````

EDIT2:More info is provided about the installation and network. Cannot get it to work :(

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:90400000-90407fff
compXXX@compXXX-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ uname -a
Linux compXXX-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
compXXX@compXXX-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ uname -r
3.19.0-25-generic
```

Comment: this question is not same as before, since even I installed it is not working

Comment: The `bcmwl` package you're trying to install is [over 2 years old](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2). That means, it was released before kernel v3.19, which you're using, became the default for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (see `kernel package linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic is not supported`). I recommend that you upgrade both 1) `bcmwl-kernel-source` and 2) less importantly your kernel to the most recent revision for your Ubuntu release (currently versions 6.30.223.248 and 3.19.43.49, respectively). If you receive a similar error, post the content of `make.log`.

Comment: If you upgrade your kernel, don't forget to upgrade both the corresponding `linux-image-*` and `linux-headers-*` packages.

Comment: Installing 6.30.223.248 bcmwl-kernel-source, has worked. Thanks @davidfoerster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the internet with a wire, then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`.  If you cannot connect to the internet with a wire, do the following:

1.) Go to settings, then Software and Updates.

2.) Click the "Other Software" tab, then make sure the check box next to `"cdrom:[...` is selected.

3.) Put the CD you used to install Ubuntu into the drive.

4.) Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`.

If you are using a USB drive:

1.) Plug in your USB drive and navigate to the root of the drive.

2.) Copy the contents of the address bar.

3.) Go to settings, then Software and Updates, then click the "Other Software" tab.

4.) Click "Add...", then enter `deb file:(what you copied)`.

5.) Click "Add Source", then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: I did not use CD, I used usb drive to install ubuntu.

Comment: I updated the instructions.

Comment: what does copy the contents of the address bar mean?

Comment: [Image](http://www.jacobspctuneup.tk/SE/AskUbuntu/1.png)